# How can my swf access stage properties from the swf that loaded it?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, cross-domain

If I have a swf that's being loaded into other peoples' swfs (which I have no control over) is there any way I can get properties from the stage (such as height, width, fullScreenHeight, etc.) or does this have to be exposed by the loading swf?

As I have no knowledge of the loading swf, you can guess which answer I'm hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the SWFs are on the same domain, they won't have any issues accessing stage and getting the correct values. However, in the loaded in SWF, be sure in it's base class constructor to listen for Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE to know when stage to available for use.

The only exception here is with Flex. If you load an AS3 SWF into a Flex application, the loaded swf gets a stage 'proxy'. However, I assume this is not your case.

Comment: Unfortunately, they're not on the same domain.  (And there's no Flex involved.)